# Angular highchart-ng installation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

i'm not able to use highcharts-ng in my angular app.
https://github.com/dmitruk/highcharts-ng

I have install it like that:

```
bower install highcharts-ng
```

And my index.js look like:

```
    'use strict';

angular.module('highchartApp', [
'ngAnimate',
'ngCookies',
'ngTouch',
'ngSanitize',
'ui.router',
'ui.bootstrap',
'highcharts-ng'
])
      .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
          .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
          });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
      })
    ;
```

What am i missing? Because juste like this i'm getting this error....

```
Module 'highcharts-ng' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or blablabla
```

Please forgive me if the solution is too easy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the javascript page in your webpage?

Comment: i'm using gulp so it should be injected automatically, like it's done with the js of other depedency.

Comment: You should definitely checking it in the resulting webpage.

Answer (score -1):

You have to save the reference to highcharts-ng in your bower file:

```
bower install highcharts-ng --save
```